# Does AngularJS save variables to file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, just wondering about its interactivity.  The AngularJS page (https://angularjs.org/) shows how inputs and mouse clicks can change variable values, but my question is, do these new values actually get saved anywhere?  If you close the application or turn off the device, will it store the new values?  Or are they just kept in temporary memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables are stored in normal javascript variables, so yes they would be lost if the user closes the application.

Like any other web application, data can be stored in the browser using local state, or persisted to a server-side backend.  If you don't want to write a backend, tools such as [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) exist to remove as much of the work as possible.